# Tiny & odd-sized field

Tags: bytefield

Bytefield is able to handle odd-sized fields (example taken from the doc):

```
\begin{bytefield}{16}
  \bitheader{0,7,8,15} \\
  \bitbox{8}{8-bit field} & \bitbox[lrt]{8}{} \\
  \wordbox[lrb]{1}{24-bit field}
\end{bytefield}
```

[image: compiled example]

I'm facing this kind of problem, but with a field sized less than the width of the figure.  Here, FCCS field is 5-bit wide, and truncated on two lines (I dropped the border lines to make it clear):

```
\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=2em]{8}
  \bitheader{0-7} \\
  \bitbox{1}{---} &
  \bitbox{3}{DT} &
  \bitbox[ltb]{4}{FCCS} \\
  \bitbox[rtb]{1}{} &
  \bitbox{6}{ConvZeros} &
  \bitbox{1}{\color{lightgray}\rule{\width}{\height}} \\
\end{bytefield}
```

[image]

Is there a way to more clearly indicate that the field continues on the next line?  E.g. by adding a "~" one the real end of the first line and at the really beginning of the second line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to alter the byte field drawing commands to conditionally add a tilde at the start or end of the field.

In the MWE below this is done by declaring a new command `\continuebox` that takes an extra argument for a tilde right or left and sets a boolean to indicate the tilde needs to be added.

Using the `xpatch` package some code is inserted in the middle of the internal `\draw@bit@picture` command of `bytefield` to check the boolean and draw a box at the same position as the normal box with the field label with the tilde in it, either at the left of the field or at the right using `\raggedleft`.

Finally the regular `\bitbox` command is redefined to set the boolean to false, to prevent printing the tilde for normal byte fields.

The tilde has a little bit of horizontal space (`0.3em`) at the left or right to make sure it fits in the box.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
% boolean to check if tilde is needed
\newif\ifbitbox@continue
% boolean to put tilde at start or end of field
\newif\ifbitbox@continueright
% new command with extra argument to put tilde
\DeclareRobustCommand{\continuebox}[4][lrtb]{%
  % set boolean for drawing tilde to true
  \bitbox@continuetrue%
  % set position boolean depending on argument #4
  \ifx#4r\bitbox@continuerighttrue\else\bitbox@continuerightfalse\fi%
  % code for drawing the field copied from \bitbox 
  \setlength{\units@wide}{\bf@bitwidth * #2}%
  \bf@parse@bitbox@arg{#1}%
  \draw@bit@picture{\strip@pt\units@wide}{\strip@pt\bf@bitheight}{#3}}
% original \bitbox command modified to set boolean to false
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bitbox}[3][lrtb]{%
  \setlength{\units@wide}{\bf@bitwidth * #2}%
  \bf@parse@bitbox@arg{#1}%
  % set boolean to false
  \bitbox@continuefalse%
  \draw@bit@picture{\strip@pt\units@wide}{\strip@pt\bf@bitheight}{#3}}

% add drawing tilde to internal field drawing command
% put box with tilde on top of regular box
% align right or left depending on boolean for position
\xpatchcmd{\draw@bit@picture}{\ifbitbox@top}{\ifbitbox@continue
    \put(0,0){\makebox(\strip@pt\units@wide,\strip@pt\bf@bitheight){\parbox{\strip@pt\units@wide\unitlength}{%
    \ifbitbox@continueright\raggedleft$\sim\hskip 0.3em$\else$\hskip 0.3em\sim$\fi\par}}}%
    \fi%
    \ifbitbox@top}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=2em]{8}
  \bitheader{0-7} \\
  \bitbox{1}{---} &
  \bitbox{3}{DT} &
  %\bitbox[ltb]{4}{FCCS} \\
  %\bitbox[rtb]{1}{} &
  \continuebox[ltb]{4}{FCCS}{r} \\
  \continuebox[rtb]{1}{}{l} &
  \bitbox{6}{ConvZeros} &
  \bitbox{1}{\color{lightgray}\rule{\width}{\height}} \\
\end{bytefield}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]